# leveraging Apache solr streaming capability to send millions of records as part of REST API

Tags: solr, solrcloud

My problem statement goes like this

" I want to leverage apache solr 8.6.1 streaming capability to send millions of records as part of spring boot REST API call. I cannot directly call solr end points due to security restrictions and also some business logic in place. So I have written the code through which I am able to read the data as stream and push it to spring boot outputstream."

When I am making the API call everytime It goes through the following code

```
StreamFactory factory = new StreamFactory().withCollectionZkHost(COLLECTION_NAME,ZK_HOST);
        SolrClientCache solrClientCache = new SolrClientCache(httpClient);

        StreamContext streamContext = new StreamContext();
        streamContext.setSolrClientCache(solrClientCache);

        String expressionStr = String.format(SEARCH_EXPRESSION,COLLECTION_NAME);
        StreamExpression expression = StreamExpressionParser.parse(expressionStr);
        TupleStream stream;
        try {
            stream = new CloudSolrStream(expression, factory);
            stream.setStreamContext(streamContext);
            stream.open();
            Tuple tuple = stream.read();
            int count = 0;
            while (!tuple.EOF) {
                String jsonStr = ++count + " " + tuple.jsonStr() + "\r\n";
                outputStream.write(jsonStr.getBytes());
                outputStream.flush();
                tuple = stream.read();
            }
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and it tries to connect to zookeeper at **stream.open** and it is taking some time.
is it possible to optimize this code so that everytime it doesn't have to connect to zookeeper and we can keep it ready before hand only.

because it is a stream that's why we have to open and close the stream with every call.
also how it will behave in the multiuser scenario.
Can anyone throw some light on it and how we can optimize it further

Comment: Any suggestions from anyone